# Grouping columns by date and time

Tags: column

I work in Communications and we collect the news related to our department and send it out by email twice daily, once in the morning and once in the afternoon. I have set up a SharePoint library to group by Date, so it groups uploaded files by the date they were added, which is great. I was wondering if I could group the files under these dates by morning and afternoon (ie. before 12:00 and after 12:00) so by the time that they were added, so that they correspond with our morning and afternoon news alerts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thats possible:

create a new calculated column in the list/library.

In the calculated field copy and paste between the quotes "=IF(HOUR(Modified)>12,"PM","AM")"

Save.

Go to view and and group by date and second by this calculated field.

Then column [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Create a choice column for the library with the two options of AM, PM, Before 12, After 12, whatever you want.

Then create a new view or modify the default view.  One option is to Group By.  You can set it to group by Date first, then by the create column.

You can do this all from Library Settings.  Getting there will depend on your version of SharePoint.